# Reset elementary OS to factory settings

Tags: settings

[image]

Can I restore elementary OS to factory settings? There are some very annoying bugs, and I font know how to fix them. Some of the bugs that I have include in the "status bar" the WiFi indicator is missing, and when I'm in steam or VLC, there icons don't show up there ether.